# Getting Values from multiple select box with POST Method

Tags: php, ajax, oracle

I have a question regarding inputting multiple values from the html list box.

so my code is,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"
      onSubmit='doSubmit()'>
    <select name="hmSelect[]" multiple class="form-control" size="15"
            onChange="getElements('<?php echo $projectName ?>','<?php echo $componentType ?>',(this.value));">
        <?php
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) {
            ?><option><?php echo $row['HEAD_MARK'] ?></option><?php
        }
        ?>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $hmSelect = intval($_POST["hmSelect"]);
    $count    = count($hmSelect);
    echo $count;
}
?>
```

That's multiple dropdown gotten from the database, user can select multiple values and process the value to be inserted again into the new table.

I don't know how to pass the hmSelect[] to process the value with isset.
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
$hms=$_POST['hmSelect'];
if ($hms)
{
foreach ($hms as $value)
{
    array_push($arr,$value);
}
}
```

you can loop through the values of drop down and process it(copying to array in this case).